# Regex for preg_replace HTML comments and empty tags in SVG files

Tags: php, html, xml, regex, svg

When Illustrator exports SVG files, it doesn't do a very good job of optimizing them. One annoying and pointless thing it puts in near the top of the file is the following HTML comment:

```
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
```

I also have multiple empty group tags with ids like so:

```
<g id="svgSteps">
</g>
<g id="svgBase">
</g>
```

Now, I'm trying to write some PHP using regex and `preg_replace` to remove things like this.
I'm completely new to regex and already tried some solutions posted on stackoverflow which didn't work for me.

For the HTML comments I tried:

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents('my_file');
$fileContent = preg_replace('/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/','',$fileContent);
file_put_contents('my_file',$fileContent);
```

Which didn't work. When I tried a `str_replace` for `<!--` instead, that worked so I know the `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` are working (no issues with permissions).

What would be the correct regex for:

1. Finding HTML comments starting with `<!--` and ending with `-->` that have whitespace, alpha-numeric characters, periods, commas, colons and brackets inside.
2. Finding tags starting with `<g` and ending with `</g>` that can have an id but only have either whitespace or nothing inside the tag.

Comment: Try: `preg_replace('/<!--.*?-->/s', '', $fileContent);`

Comment: and `preg_replace('/<g id="svgSteps">\s+<\/g>/', '', $fileContent);`

Comment: @anubhava thanks but it doesn't seem to be working for me. The comment remains in tact.

Comment: @va5ja the groups all have different IDs as you can see in my example above. Is there a way to target empty groups with any ids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
    preg_replace("/((<g id=\".*\">)|(<g>))[\s]*(<\/g>)/",'',$fileContent)
    preg_replace("/(<!--)[\s\S]*(-->)/",'',$fileContent)
```

Comment: Ah right this does seem to be working but now I've realised it's not putting the new file contents back in the file for some reason. Don't suppose you'd know why that is?

Comment: not to worry, it was a permissions issue with the file!

Comment: Works great except one small thing. in the regex for the group tags, you've used double quotation marks to open the statement and also inside the statement for the ids. This would need to be escaped or single quotation marks used to open the regex.

Comment: @Coop - thanks for pointing that out, I tested at http://regexr.com (great for testing next time), not using PHP, so that slipped my mind.

Comment: This solution is not very flexible, it won't work with most of other SVG files you might want to use in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$fileContent = preg_replace('#<!--.*?-->#s', '', $fileContent);
$fileContent = preg_replace('#<(\w+)(?:\s+[^>]+)?>\s*</\1>#s', '', $fileContent);
```

I made it in two separate `preg_replace` instructions, so tags containing only comments will also be removed.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

```
<?php
$fileContent = '<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  --> asdlfhjlkasdjhfasdf asd <g id="kjkjkh" /> askdjghf ag <g id="eeee" > </g>ahsdjghakjhglkjdahlg';
$fileContent = preg_replace('/(<\!--(.|\s)*-->)?([\n\w\W]*)?/','$3',$fileContent);
$fileContent = preg_replace('/<[gG]?\s+[Ii][Dd]="?\w+"\s*(?:\/>|>)[\s\t]*(<\/[gG]>)?/', ' ',$fileContent);
echo($fileContent);
?>
```